# Still getting 404 page not found on Django using correct route files and settings

Tags: python, django

I'm going through the polls Django tutorial and have searched for answers to this. So far:

1. I made sure I'm using the right directories. The main urls.py is in mysite/mysite/, the polls urls.py is in mysite/polls/urls.py.
2. Tried adding 'polls' to INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py of mysite/mysite.
3. Am making sure that I am requesting 127.0.0.1:8000/polls and not 127.0.0.1:8000
4. I am using Python 3.4 and Django 1.9, same as the tutorial.

I am still receiving this message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^polls/
^admin/
The current URL, polls, didn't match any of these.
```

**mysite/mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**mysite/polls/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^%', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**mysite/polls/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world")
```

Comment: You have a typo in mysite/polls/urls.py, the percent sign instead of the dollar.

Comment: url(r'^%', views.index, name='index'), to $ 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]

Comment: Gosh I feel like an idiot, thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `polls/urls.py`
change `url(r'^%', views.index, name='index')` to `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')`.

Also in your urls.py, you have route for `127.0.0.1:8000/polls/` and you request for `127.0.0.1:8000/polls` . Notice the trailing slash.

So you should request to `127.0.0.1:8000/polls/` .

Add `APPEND_SLASH = True` in your `settings.py` file so that it would redirect `127.0.0.1:8000/polls` to `127.0.0.1:8000/polls/` .

Answer (score 0):

So i tried your Index view with your urls.py.
It works, the only thing different is in your "Request URL, you must request for - 127.0.0.1:8000/polls/%

changing your urls to

url('^/%', index) - polls URLs.py
url('^polls', include('polls.urls')) - project URLs

This will work.